# Why data cleared from textbox when click enter when converting Hijri date to gregorian Date c# windows application?

Tags: c#, .net, date-conversion

I want to convert Hijri Date to Gregorian date and vise versa, I found the following solution class in this link

> https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8838/Convert-date-from-Hijri-Calendar-to-Gregorian-Cale?msg=5688246#xx5688246xx

I tried the class code :

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;

namespace Bahsas
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Dates.
    /// </summary>
    public class Dates
    {
        private HttpContext cur;

        private const int startGreg=1900;
        private const int endGreg=2100;
        private string[] allFormats={"yyyy/MM/dd","yyyy/M/d",
            "dd/MM/yyyy","d/M/yyyy",
            "dd/M/yyyy","d/MM/yyyy","yyyy-MM-dd",
            "yyyy-M-d","dd-MM-yyyy","d-M-yyyy",
            "dd-M-yyyy","d-MM-yyyy","yyyy MM dd",
            "yyyy M d","dd MM yyyy","d M yyyy",
            "dd M yyyy","d MM yyyy"};
        private CultureInfo arCul;
        private CultureInfo enCul;
        private HijriCalendar h;
        private GregorianCalendar g;

        public Dates()
        {
            cur = HttpContext.Current;

            arCul=new CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            enCul=new CultureInfo("en-US");

            h=new  HijriCalendar();
            g=new GregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendarTypes.USEnglish);

            arCul.DateTimeFormat.Calendar=h;           
        }

           /// <summary>
        /// Check if string is hijri date and then return true 
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="hijri"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsHijri(string hijri)
        {
            if (hijri.Length<=0)
            {

                cur.Trace.Warn("IsHijri Error: Date String is Empty");
                return false;
            }
            try
            {    
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(hijri,allFormats,
                     arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                if (tempDate.Year>=startGreg && tempDate.Year<=endGreg)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("IsHijri Error :"+hijri.ToString()+"\n"+
                                  ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Check if string is Gregorian date and then return true 
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="greg"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool IsGreg(string greg)
        {
            if (greg.Length<=0)
            {

                cur.Trace.Warn("IsGreg :Date String is Empty");
                return false;
            }
            try
            {    
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(greg,allFormats,
                    enCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                if (tempDate.Year>=startGreg && tempDate.Year<=endGreg)
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("IsGreg Error :"+greg.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Formatted Hijri date string 
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="date"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FormatHijri(string date ,string format)
        {
            if (date.Length<=0)
            {                
                cur.Trace.Warn("Format :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {                       
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(date,
                   allFormats,arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString(format,arCul.DateTimeFormat);                            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("Date :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Returned Formatted Gregorian date string
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="date"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string FormatGreg(string date ,string format)
        {
            if (date.Length<=0)
            {                
                cur.Trace.Warn("Format :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(date,allFormats,
                    enCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString(format,enCul.DateTimeFormat);                            
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("Date :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Return Today Gregorian date and return it in yyyy/MM/dd format
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GDateNow()
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",enCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("GDateNow :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Return formatted today Gregorian date based on your format
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GDateNow(string format)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToString(format,enCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("GDateNow :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        } 

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Today Hijri date and return it in yyyy/MM/dd format
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string HDateNow()
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",arCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HDateNow :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Return formatted today hijri date based on your format
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>

        public string HDateNow(string format)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Now.ToString(format,arCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HDateNow :\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }            
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Hijri Date to it's equivalent Gregorian Date
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="hijri"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string HijriToGreg(string hijri)
        {            
            if (hijri.Length<=0)
            {

                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(hijri,allFormats,
                   arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",enCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :"+hijri.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Hijri Date to it's equivalent Gregorian Date
        /// and return it in specified format
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="hijri"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string HijriToGreg(string hijri,string format)
        {
            if (hijri.Length<=0)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(hijri,
                   allFormats,arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString(format,enCul.DateTimeFormat);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("HijriToGreg :"+hijri.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Gregoian Date to it's equivalent Hijir Date
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="greg"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GregToHijri(string greg)
        {
            if (greg.Length<=0)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("GregToHijri :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(greg,allFormats,
                    enCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd",arCul.DateTimeFormat);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("GregToHijri :"+greg.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Convert Hijri Date to it's equivalent Gregorian Date and
        /// return it in specified format
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="greg"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="format"></PARAM>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GregToHijri(string greg,string format)
        {            
            if (greg.Length<=0)
            {                
                cur.Trace.Warn("GregToHijri :Date String is Empty");
                return "";
            }
            try
            {               
                DateTime tempDate=DateTime.ParseExact(greg,allFormats,
                    enCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return tempDate.ToString(format,arCul.DateTimeFormat);                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("GregToHijri :"+greg.ToString()+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return "";
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Return Gregrian Date Time as digit stamp
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string GTimeStamp()
        {
            return GDateNow("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Return Hijri Date Time as digit stamp
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string HTimeStamp()
        {
            return HDateNow("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compare two instances of string date 
        /// and return indication of their values 
        /// </summary>
        /// <PARAM name="d1"></PARAM>
        /// <PARAM name="d2"></PARAM>
        /// <returns>positive d1 is greater than d2,
        /// negative d1 is smaller than d2, 0 both are equal</returns>
        public int Compare(string d1,string d2)
        {
            try
            {
                DateTime date1=DateTime.ParseExact(d1,allFormats,
                    arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                DateTime date2=DateTime.ParseExact(d2,allFormats,
                    arCul.DateTimeFormat,DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                return DateTime.Compare(date1,date2);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                cur.Trace.Warn("Compare :"+"\n"+ex.Message);
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then i created 2 textbox HijriDate and GreDate and i need for example when write the date in gregorian and click ENTER to convert it to Hijri and vise versa .
I tried the following code :

```
private void hijriDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
      greDate.text =  date.HijriToGreg(hijriDate.Text);
    }
}

private void greDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
    {
       hijriDate.text =  date.GregToHijri(greDate.Text);
    } 
}
```

When i type hijri date in hijridate textbox and click ENTER the date in Hijridate textbox cleared and converted to gregorian date in greDate textbox , also When i type gregorian date in gredate textbox and click ENTER the date in gredate textbox cleared and converted to hijri date in hijridate textbox 
why its cleared and how i will keep both dates hijri date and gregorian date?

Comment: Do you have complete example code you're running? I have checked your code you have provided but do not see anything that would lead to emptying the input.

Comment: @Scircia this is the complete code i use in my example no other codes

Comment: i might be mistaken but i don't think this is the complete code. You have defined two variables: hijriDate and greDate, yet in any code you have provided is there no sign of any of those properties being defined. This leads me to believe that the example above is not complete. Anyway, could you check if you have anything in your code that will trigger [myInput.text = ""] or [myInput.Clear()] or [myInput.text = string.Empty]?

Comment: @Scircia , I checked the code there is no clear() or string.empty or "", i think maybe i need to use another event not keydown ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can check multiline property for the textbox hijriDate and greDate , if it is true change it to false , when you click ENTER it goes to the next line and its not hide.

Then if you need to calculate age from birth of date you use the follwing code :

```
private void hijriDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)

                {
                greDate.Text = date.HijriToGreg(hijriDate.Text);
                int age = (int)((DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(greDate.Text)).TotalDays / 365.242199);
                textAge.Text =  age.ToString();
                greDate.Focus();
            }

        }
```

Comment: thank you thats it working now :) multiline = true before

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Did you verify the dates in respective variables?
It may be that pressing 'Enter' has moved the text so it is not visible on screen.</strike>

---

I wrote the following code and it is working fine:

```
    private void hijriDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            greDate.Text = new Dates().HijriToGreg(hijriDate.Text);
        }
    }

    private void greDate_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            hijriDate.Text = new Dates().GregToHijri(greDate.Text);
        }
    }
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEQFg.jpg)

Comment: what do you mean can you give example sorry i am still new to .NET.